# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EntityLayer.Concrete.AppUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Where am I making a mistake? Can you help me ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. It should have been like below.
Thanks

[image]